# Kreyszig's functional analysis exercise of Fredolm Type section 8.6 Problem 15

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have no idea how to compute this.
Is this problem says that we need to find $f(s)\neq 0$ such that $Tf(s)=0,$ then $x$ in (1) might not exist?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: For what purpose we consider onto-ness?

Comment: Thanks, now I have a problem to prove surjectivity. Could you give me a hint!

Comment: Sorry, I typed it backwards. The operator is not surjective, but it is injective. This follows from Fourier series (you can swap the sum and integral by uniform convergence and get a Fourier series for $Tx(s)$).

Answer (score 1):

Your operator is injective: if $Tx=0$, then $x=0$. This requires fiddling a bit with Fourier series. Because $k(s,t)$ is continuous (uniform limit of continuous functions), the operator $T$ is compact. A compact operator on an infinite-dimensional normed space can never be surjective. So $Tx=0$ has only the trivial solution, but $Tx=y$ has no solution for some $y$.

An easier example is to take $X=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, and
$$
Tx=(x_1,x_2/2,x_3/3,\ldots). 
$$
It is then trivial to check that $T$ is injective, and that for instance the sequence $y=(1,1/2,1/3,\ldots)$ is not in the range of $T$.